# Sending a GET request to the Facebook Graph API which contains the user’s latitude and longitude for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, core-location

Does anyone know how I might go about sending a GET request to the Facebook Graph API which contains the user’s latitude and longitude.

this is for iOS

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean getting Users Current location using Facebook Graph Api ?

Here is a Sample code which i borrowed from  sample application provided by Facebook (Hackbook for ios) Link:https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook

```
- (void)apiGraphSearchPlace:(CLLocation *)location {

    currentAPICall = kAPIGraphSearchPlace;
    NSString *centerLocation = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f",
                                location.coordinate.latitude,
                                location.coordinate.longitude];
    HackbookAppDelegate *delegate = (HackbookAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"place",  @"type",
                                   centerLocation, @"center",
                                   @"1000",  @"distance",
                                   nil];
    [centerLocation release];
    [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"search" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: thanks! I've been trying to use that but have run into problems integrating it into my app.